# How to change the function keys on a mac with applescript or terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I am trying to make a script which can change the function keys on my keyboard to standard function keys, such as F1, F2, and then toggle it back on, so it is easier for me to use the function keys easier on Minecraft, while being able to work without having to go to system preferences to change it back.

Comment: man I really want the same script for EVE online. have you had any luck with this?

Comment: nope. no luck with this.